# Feature Labels wrong with GeoJSON data source

Tags: qgis

**EDIT:**

I found out that the attribute table changes when zooming, my GeoJSON output does not change however.

I am working on a QGIS project where I've imported points as a GeoJSON data source from a web server. When I label the points ind QGIS and select the name field as the label field. I get the correct result initially.
When I zoom, the labels will change to some other field value from GeoJSON.
I've tried several QGIS versions and also changed the GeoJSON output for the field positions to be static.

[image: Wrong Labels]

[image: Correct Labels]

[image: Attribute Table]

[image: Label Settings]

Please help!!